# Error when using named type (IdentityUser), works fine when assigning it to var, why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

One line of code, when assigning to either the proper type vs var behaves differently and I do not understand why.

The below line throws a Null Exception error. When I trace through FindUser() it is indeed returning the proper user object.

```
IdentityUser identityUser = await _repo.FindUser(id, pass);
```

The below line does work as expected, no Null Exception, and the only change is assigning it to var instead of IdentityUser

```
var identityUser = await _repo.FindUser(id, pass);
```

My question: Why is this happening? Could it be indicative of a code smell somewhere?

Comment: Can you post a small but complete example that others can run?

Comment: Either remove `await` or replace with `FindAsync`. Right now you are trying to await for syncronos operation.

Comment: Thank @trailmax that did it, kind of a bonehead mistake there eh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @trailmax pointed out, I was trying to await a synchronous method. Worked when replaced with...

```
IdentityUser identityUser = _repo.FindUser(id, pass).Result;
```